# How to record CPU usage of a single app from top command?

Tags: linux, command, cpu-usage, record

I know 'grep' command can help me do this:
`$ top -bd 0.5 -o +%CPU | grep "zoom" > cpu_usage.log`

Then I can use another python code to extract the figures but I also want to grab the **timestamp** from the first line of 'top' result. Is there a way to do it? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

After some research on the internet and reading document (`man top` / `man greb`), we can add timestamp by searching for another keyword in the first line which contains its timestamp.

The first lines of `top` looks like this:

```
top - 17:05:43 up 11:08,  1 user,  load average: 1.16, 1.05, 1.18   
Tasks: 294 total,   1 running, 293 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  3.6 us,  1.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 94.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :   7765.0 total,   1048.7 free,   3520.4 used,   3195.9 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   2048.0 total,   1953.7 free,     94.2 used.   3294.5 avail Mem
```

Notice that the timestamp is the first line and contains `"top - "`. So I will add another search string `"top - "` in my command with "\|" between the two search strings signalling the system that I want to get lines that have either/both strings, like this:

```
$ top -bd 0.5 -o +%CPU | grep "top - \|zoom" > cpu_usage.log
```

Done!